# What does "%3d" mean in a printf statement?

Tags: c++, printf

In this code what is the role of the symbol `%3d`? I know that % means refer to a variable.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int t, i, num[3][4];
    for(t=0; t<3; ++t)
        for(i=0; i<4; ++i)
            num[t][i] = (t*4)+i+1;
    /* now print them out */
    for(t=0; t<3; ++t) {
        for(i=0; i<4; ++i)
            printf("%3d ", num[t][i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778785/what-does-6d-mean-in-printf

Comment: Nitpick: that’s probably C code, not C++.

Comment: Voted as duplicate to the above - we don't need a seperate *"what does `%Nd` mean?"* for every possible `N`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "%.6d" mean in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778785/what-does-6d-mean-in-printf)

Answer (score 22):

`%3d` can be broken down as follows:

- `%` means "Print a variable here";
- `3` means "use at least 3 spaces to display, padding as needed";
- `d` means "The variable will be an integer";

Putting these together, it means: "Print an integer, taking minimum 3 spaces".

See [cplusplus — printf](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for more information.

Answer (score 12):

That is a format specifier to print a decimal number (`d`) in three (at least) digits (`3`).

From `man printf`:

> An optional decimal digit string
>   specifying a minimum field width.  If
>   the converted value has fewer
>   characters than the field width, it
>   will be padded with spaces on the left
>   (or right, if the left-adjustment flag
>   has been given) to fill out the field
>   width.

Comment: opengroup.org is better: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html

Answer (score 6):

Take a look here:

`Print("%3d",X);`

- If X is 1234, it prints `1234`.
- If X is 123, it prints `123`.
- If X is 12, it prints `_12` where `_` is a leading single whitespace character.
- If X is 1, it prints `__1`  where `__` is two leading whitespacce characters.

Answer (score 1):

An example to enlighten existing answers:

```
printf("%3d" , x);
```

When:

`x` is 1234 prints `1234`

`x` is 123 prints `123`

`x` is 12 prints `12` with an extra padding (space)

`x` is 1 prints `1` with two extra paddings (spaces)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the field width between the % and d(for decimal). It represents the total number of characters printed. 
A positive value, as mentioned in another answer, right-aligns the output and is the default. 
A negative value left-aligns the text.
example:

```
int a = 3;
printf("|%-3d|", a);
```

The output:

```
|3  |
```

You could also specify the field width as an additional parameter by using the * character:

```
int a = 3;
printf("|%*d|", 5, a);
```

which gives:

```
|    3|
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a formatting specification. %3d says: print the argument as a decimal, of width 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, it means to print an integer padded to three digits with spaces. The % introduces a format specifier, the 3 indicates 3 digits, and the d indicates an integer. Thus, the value of num[t][i] is printed to the screen as a value such as "  1", "  2", " 12", etc.

Answer (score 0):

2/3 or any integer is padding/width .it means ex for 3 ,minimum 3 space if we print a=4 then it print like  4,here two space left before 4 because it is one character

Comment: You are answering a quite old question which already has some well received answers. I can't see any added value in your answer. So, what's your reason of posting it?