# Char matrix overflow

Tags: c, printf, overflow

Code is very simple, I am trying to make a battleship game but still in early stages

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
int i = 0;                                   /* Loop counter  */
int player = 0;                              /* Player number - 1 or 2  */
int go = 0;                                  /* Square selection number for turn */
int row = 0;                                 /* Row index for a square  */
int column = 0;                              /* Column index for a square  */
int line = 0;                                /* Row or column index in checking loop */
int winner = 0;                              /* The winning player  */
char board[8][8] = {                         /* The board                            */
                   {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'},               /* Initial values are reference numbers */
                   {'9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'},        /* used to select a vacant square for   */
                   {'17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'},        /* a turn.                              */
                   {'25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32'},
                   {'33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40'},
                   {'41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48'},
                   {'49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56'},
                   {'57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64'}
                 };

/* The main game loop. The game continues for up to 64 turns */
/* As long as there is no winner                            */
for( i = 0; i<64 && winner==0; i++)
{
  /* Display the board */
printf("\n\n");
  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2], board[0][3], board[0][4], board[0][5], board[0][6], board[0][7]);

  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2], board[1][3], board[1][4], board[1][5], board[1][6], board[1][7]);

  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2], board[2][3], board[2][4], board[2][5], board[2][6], board[2][7]);

  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[3][0], board[3][1], board[3][2], board[3][3], board[3][4], board[3][5], board[3][6], board[3][7]);

  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[4][0], board[4][1], board[4][2], board[4][3], board[4][4], board[4][5], board[4][6], board[4][7]);

  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[5][0], board[5][1], board[5][2], board[5][3], board[5][4], board[5][5], board[5][6], board[5][7]);

  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[6][0], board[6][1], board[6][2], board[6][3], board[6][4], board[6][5], board[6][6], board[6][7]);

  printf(" %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c | %2c\n", board[7][0], board[7][1], board[7][2], board[7][3], board[7][4], board[7][5], board[7][6], board[7][7]);
```

I am trying to get an output as something like

```
1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8
9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |  15 |  16
17 |  18 |  19 |  20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |  24
```

and all the way till 64, but instead what I am getting is

```
1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8
9  |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6
7  |  8  |  9  |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4
```

and so on...
It only shows the digit on the right side of the number

as for the error message I am getting it's about what follows the `char board[8][8]`
and it is for all 8 lines

> > > Multiple markers at this line
> > >
> > > ```
> > > -overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
> > >
> > > -multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
> > > ```

I am pretty new to c/anci-c so any info would help

Comment: Why are u writing %2c , whats your aim?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806093/what-does-3d-mean-in-a-printf-statement

Comment: the 2 is just for the extra space

Comment: `'10'` is a valid _character constant_, yet not what OP wants.  Just use `10`.  And use `printf(" %2d `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose your `board` be of type `char`, which means everything it contains should be exactly 1 character long. However, you assign '10', '11', etc. and they contain 2 characters. So, the compiler tries to convert 2 characters into 1 character char. But since 2 > 1, it overflows, which results in only one character (apparentrly the last one) to be assigned. Also, since it's basically a guess on part of the system, it also gives you the second error message about it.

You'd want to change your `board` type from `char` to `string` or `int` (of course deleting the single quotes around the numbers). You'd also want you `printf()` function changed to correct format.

Comment: Detail: `'10'` is not a _2 character string_, but a _integer character constant_ containing more than one character, which has implementation defined behavior. IAC, it is not what OP needs (as this answer directs).

Comment: Thank you, @chux, I'm fixing the answer to reflect this fact.

Answer (score 0):

These are not valid characters `{'17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'},` as they consist of 2 characters. If you want to store text that is longer than 1 character you need a string or if you're wanting the number, you should remove the single quotes. Either way, your `printf` statements would be also need changing as you'd either want `%2s` or `%2d`